# Iterate over json data with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

When I alert the output in the example below I get the correct output, but when I `console.log` the output, I get: `Number {}`

```
"width": [ 25, 50, 75, 100 ],

jQuery.each(width, function() {
  new_width = this;
  console.log(new_width);
  alert(new_width);
  document.querySelectorAll('#source').forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.style.width = new_width;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `jQuery.each()` to loop through the array. When accessing via `this` you receive a `Number` object, not an integer value, hence the `{}` output to the log. There's several ways to fix this:

1) Use the arguments passed to the function instead of the `this` reference:

```js
var foo = { "width": [ 25, 50, 75, 100 ] }
jQuery.each(foo.width, function(i, value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2) Use `toString()` or `valueOf()` on the object. Side note, `alert()` in your question works because it calls `toString()` under the hood.

```js
var foo = { "width": [ 25, 50, 75, 100 ] }
jQuery.each(foo.width, function() {
  console.log(this.toString());
  console.log(this.valueOf());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

3) Don't use jQuery to loop through a plain array of values. Use a `forEach()` loop:

```js
var foo = { "width": [ 25, 50, 75, 100 ] }
foo.width.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My preference is for the latter method, but any of them work.

Comment: A simpler explanation is that "this" in the context of the execution is the js Object. You need the actual value for each item, so you need to use the "each" function parameters(first is the index, second is the actual value).

Comment: `A simpler explanation is that "this" in the context of the execution is the js Object` To which JS object are you referring? It's a `Number` object, as I explained within the answer.

Comment: The loop constructor object. I know you explained in detail, I just voted up for the detailed explanation and tried to shorten the explanation.